# Organize DIV content with Bootstrap-4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am not able to find solution to aligning / organizing my div content with Bootstrap. I don't quite understand how it works

aling-items- *
text-*
aling-self- *
justify-items- *
justify-self- *

I am trying to organize my website in the following way:

[image]

but I am not able to align the contents so that it is completely joined to the left or right edges or so that the content is left, whether it be img, text or another div in the center of it. I would like to avoid using padding or margins since I am trying to make a responsive content and then they can give me other problems. Thank you very much for your help, greetings.

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us so that we can help. We can't help you fix code we cannot see. Take a look at how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and update your question with details so that we can see wher the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to get started:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/3ybdpn09/15/) to play-around

```css
.MainDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 210px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
}

.First {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 5px;
}

.FirstSubDiv {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
}

.Second {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

.SecondSubDiv {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.Third {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 5px;
}

.ThirdSubDiv {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <div class="First">
    <div class="FirstSubDiv">
      contents are in left;
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Second">
    <div class="SecondSubDiv">
      contents are in center;
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Third">
    <div class="ThirdSubDiv">
      contents are in right;
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

All the information you require is provided here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/

In the beginning, you can just copy and paste the boostrap html and tweak it. Gradually you'll get the gist of it (after test and trial) and you'll be able to work on it on your own.

**EDIT**
[https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rej1B.png)

View the image attached. If that is what you're looking to do, visit this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

Comment: I have tested all the bootstrap documentation tags. Nothing works for me. Bootstrap only aligns the divs, not the content in them. I need move the green content not the blue one

Comment: if bootstrap aligns the divs, surround the content with divs and apply the changes to it. Furthermore, I think you'll find this documentation useful for your purposes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/